# Difference access between the server and my computer mac

Tags: macos, symfony-1.4, lamp, chmod

I retrieve a project in symfony 1.4 . The project is currently running on an Ubuntu server (LAMP). When I run the project on my Mac , the photos do not appear yet the path is good . I think it is a problem of access rule but i am not an expert. 
I Thank You in advance to help me.

As attachment files of my mac and the server.

On my mac : 
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincentmoulene  _www      204 17 fév 22:43 README.md
drwxrwxrwx  17 vincentmoulene  _www      578 14 jan 22:51 apps
drwxrwxrwx   5 vincentmoulene  _www      170  4 mar 22:26 cache
drwxrwxrwx   8 vincentmoulene  _www      272 26 fév 11:17 config
-rw-r--r--   1 vincentmoulene  _www     4478  3 mar 17:08 connection_sequel.spf
drwxrwxrwx   5 vincentmoulene  _www      170  4 mar 22:26 data
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincentmoulene  _www  3263056  6 fév 12:20 emoovio_2015-02-06.sql
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincentmoulene  _www  3325677 16 fév 18:08 emoovio_2015-02-16.sql
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincentmoulene  _www    11510 14 jan 20:44 index.html
drwxrwxrwx   8 vincentmoulene  _www      272  6 fév 16:58 lib
drwxrwxrwx  57 vincentmoulene  _www     1938 26 fév 16:02 log
-rw-r--r--   1 vincentmoulene  _www     1364  2 mar 12:19 main.cf
drwxrwxrwx   4 vincentmoulene  _www      136 14 jan 21:15 nbproject
drwxrwxrwx   4 vincentmoulene  _www      136 14 jan 22:49 plugins
drwxrwxrwx   6 vincentmoulene  _www      204  6 fév 16:58 sfFormExtraPlugin
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincentmoulene  _www      446 14 jan 20:44 symfony
drwxrwxrwx   6 vincentmoulene  _www      204  6 fév 16:58 test
drwxrwxrwx  17 vincentmoulene  _www      578  2 mar 15:29 web

On the server : 
drwxrwxrwx 12      777 root      4096 Feb 26 10:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Dec 17 13:17 ../
drwxrwxrwx 14 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  3  2014 apps/
drwxrwxrwx  4      777 www-data  4096 Feb 25 14:55 cache/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 29 10:35 config/
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 29 10:35 data/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     root     11510 Dec 17 13:17 index.html*
drwxrwxrwx  7 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  3  2014 lib/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 25 15:19 log/
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  2  2014 nbproject/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  3  2014 plugins/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   446 Feb 20  2013 symfony*
drwxrwxrwx  5 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  3  2014 test/
drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 28  2014 web/

Comment: Are you getting HTTP response 404 ? Or something else ? what do you get in you apache error log ? and access log (for http return codes) ?

Comment: sudo ./symfony project:permissions from your project root <- it should set right permissions on all required folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I got a functional site to improve it. This site is currently in production and runs on a LAMP stack (Ubuntu 14.04 , ....) .

To work on it , I recover the project . I work on Mac ( MAMP ) .

Indeed, the concern I have is that some pages are not available ... Therefore, I tried to change the rights but to no avail .

Then I tried to run two possibilities:

1) using Apache / Mysql run as www (Apache) and mysql ( mysql) : You do not -have permission to access this server /.../on (error 403).

2) using Apache / Mysql run as user (Apache) and user ( mysql) : The requested URL was not found /.../ on this server (error 404).

And in my apache_error.log : Directory index forbidden by Options directive: